# How to determine if an Android phone can capture video?

Tags: android, video-capture

Android 1.6 supports video capture, however, not all phones will support video capture.  Is there a way I can tell if the phone I am running on supports video capture or not?

Comment: You can start Camera Activity and include Try Catch to determine if it is starting or not. if not then you will come to know that it doesnt include video recording feature

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find an official way to do this. The only way I know is to assume that all Android phones will support video capture, so if the phone is running 1.5 (3) or greater, it will support video capture.

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```